# By Pass Method for Instruction Pipeline

Tags: multithreading, assembly, computer-science, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Hi Suppose the below instruction :

```
R1<-M1
R2<-M2
R3<-R1*R2
M3<-R3
```

Now We Will create a pipeline like below pipeline without bypassing:[XXX : bubble]

```
IF1 ID1 EX1 ME1 WB1
    IF2 ID2 EX2 ME2 WB2
        IF3 XXX XXX XXX ID3 EX3 WB3
        XXX XXX XXX XXX IF4 ID4 EX4 WB4
```

And We will create a pipeline with by-passing like below pipeline:[XXX : bubble]

```
IF1 ID1 EX1 ME1 WB1
    IF2 ID2 EX2 ME2 WB2
        IF3 XXX ID3 EX3 WB3
        XXX XXX IF4 ID4 EX4 WB4
```

We should wait until WB1 and WB2 to be done, then we can execute Instruction 3.
So in bypassing method we will store R1 and R2 values after the EX1 and EX2 levels into a buffer.

But...
In by-passing way,after EX1 , how can we get the register R1 value ?? we haven't reach to the WB1 value . Why we need a buffer , Why not to read R1 directly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value read from memory to be loaded into R1 hasn't yet been written to the register file. If you were to read the value from R1, you would get the value R1 contained before the R1<-M1 instruction. The new R1 value is stored in the ME->WB pipeline register after ME1.

Comment: Is it true that after ID1  , we will create a buffer in size of R1 and the we copy data from ID1 into our buffer ? and it is after WB1 that we have done the storing operation into R1.

Comment: Yes, between the pipeline stages there are buffers that keep the state of the pipeline between clock cycles. And yes, it is WB1 that writes R1 into the register file and updates it with the new value read from memory in ME1.

Comment: what is register file? in easy!!

Comment: The register file is just the piece of memory in the CPU that keeps the values of the registers.

Comment: No, it's the main storage for the registers. It's not temporary memory.